# Q: Reverse the numbers using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to reverse the numbers by vertical line using jquery, here's my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<textarea id="input" rows="4" style="width:100%; height:100px; resize:none;" spellcheck="false" wrap="off">38.00|34.20


44.00|39.60

29.50|26.55



44.00|39.60


29.50|26.55

46.00|41.40
40.00|36.00

39.50|35.55


29.50|26.55</textarea>
<textarea id="output" rows="4" style="width:100%; height:100px; resize:none;" spellcheck="false" wrap="off"></textarea>
<button id="process">Process!</button>
</body>
```

Input:

> 34.20|38.00
>
> 39.60|44.00
>
> 26.55|29.50
>
> 39.60|44.00
>
> 26.55|29.50
>
> 41.40|46.00
>
> 36.00|40.00
>
> 35.55|39.50
>
> 26.55|29.50

Output:

> 38.00|34.20
>
> 44.00|39.60
>
> 29.50|26.55
>
> 44.00|39.60
>
> 29.50|26.55
>
> 46.00|41.40
>
> 40.00|36.00
>
> 39.50|35.55
>
> 29.50|26.55

Hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```
$('#process').click(function(){
    $('#output').val($('#input').val().replace(/^(.+)\|(.+)$/mg, '$2|$1'))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tfjuttr6/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the html and try this :-

Instead of `<textarea>` use `<div>` as shown :-

HTML :-

```
<div id="div1">
<p>44.00|39.60</p>

<p>29.50|26.55</p>

<p>44.00|39.60</p>

<p>29.50|26.55</p>

<p>46.00|41.40</p>

<p>40.00|36.00</p>

<p>39.50|35.55</p>

<p>29.50|26.55</p>
</div>
```

jQuery :-

```
$('div#div1 p').each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).html().split('|')[1] + '|' + $(this).html().split('|')[0])
});
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tu9ctw1g/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer.
Checked

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
var txt="";
$.each(lines,function(index,value){
txt=txt+value.split('|').reverse().join('|')+'\n';
    });
$('textarea').val(txt);
```

Thanks